# How to get the url of currently playing video in Webview(get .mp4 video url)

Tags: android, webview

I want to load a url on `webview`, such that when find a video on that page, if I play that video then how can I get the video url ?

I already used `WebViewClient` methods such as `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)`